# SingleChildScrollView rendering overflow when viewport greater than maxwidth

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm trying to set web content to have a maximum width (the orange in the image), and always fill the available height, which I've achieved.

However when the window is wider than the maximum content width, and the window height is less than the height of the content, header, and footer combined. I'm getting a rendering overflow.
When what I'm after is for content to hold it's height, and the scroll to enable.

[image: overflow example]

Note: the problem seems to go way if each text is only 1 line worth.

I've tried using **CustomeScrollView** with a **SliverFillRemaining**, but I get the same problem.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Scrollable Layout',
      home: ScrollableLayout(),
    );
  }
}

class ContentWidthContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ContentWidthContainer({Key? key, required this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            width: double.infinity,
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: 960,
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 75),
            child: child),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollableLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollableLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
              ),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ContentWidthContainer(
                      child: Container(
                          color: Colors.indigo,
                          height: 200,
                          child: const Text('Header: Fixed Height')),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ContentWidthContainer(
                        child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: Column(
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                    'ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                              ],
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ContentWidthContainer(
                      child: Container(
                          color: Colors.indigo,
                          height: 200,
                          child: const Text('Footer: Fixed Height')),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On changing it to use a Column, with just 2 children, and the alignment set to `SpaceBetween`, the overflow problem disappears when you make the window width but shorter than the content.

```
class ScrollableSpaceBetweenLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollableSpaceBetweenLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black12, // the background / sides
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      color: Colors.indigo,
                      height: 200,
                      child: const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text('Header: Fixed Height'))),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: 960,
                      minHeight: max(viewportConstraints.maxHeight - 400, 0),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 75),
                    child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                    'ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Container(
                                child: const Text('spacer'),
                                height: 1,
                                color: Colors.red)
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      color: Colors.indigo,
                      height: 200,
                      child: const Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text('Footer: Fixed Height'))),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the height of the header and footer is 200 each, then the height of the middle content should be less than 400.

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 400
```

Therefore change your code to

```
 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) 
        {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
              ),
              child: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ContentWidthContainer(
                      child: Container(
                          color: Colors.indigo,
                          height: 200,
                          child: const Text('Header: Fixed Height')),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ContentWidthContainer(
                        child: Container(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 400,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: Column(
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                    'ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                                Text('Content'),
                              ],
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ContentWidthContainer(
                      child: Container(
                          color: Colors.indigo,
                          height: 200,
                          child: const Text('Footer: Fixed Height')),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi Meysam, thank you for your feedback.
The design I'm trying to implement doesn't have a sticky header or footer, and need to be part of the whole page that will scroll.

Comment: @OneGoodRun hi, Since you want the header and footer to be scrolled, so you have to reduce the middle height from the height of the header and footer. I edited the answer.

Comment: Hi Meysam, hmm, I still need to preserve the visibility of the content.
This appears to make the content within the Expanded disappear as the screen gets shorter instead of activating the scroll.

Comment: I tested your code. It works properly. Probably due to Chrome browser overflow